# Finding the domain of $ f(x)= 2\arcsin \left(\frac{x-2}{x+1}\right) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can somebody tell me how to find the domain of this function, please?
$$ f(x)= 2\arcsin \left(\frac{x-2}{x+1}\right)$$

Comment: Solve what? That's not an equation.

Comment: What are you supposed yo do with this stuff?

Comment: Here’s a hint. Arcsin is normally defined between $x=-1$ and $x=1$.  So what does this mean concerning the inside?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What have you tried? Without giving an attempt - no one can give a good explanation to cater to your current understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument limits are $\pm 1 $ for arc sine function.

So solve for two $x$ domain values:

$$ +1 =  \left(\frac{x-2}{x+1}\right)  $$
does not give a finite limit, upper limit $x<\infty$

$$ -1 =  \left(\frac{x-2}{x+1}\right)  $$

$x$ lower limit

$$\rightarrow x=\frac12 $$
Domain

$$ \frac12 <x< \infty$$

Comment: I more or less understand this but i am confused with 2arcsin... I would probbaly know how to solve it if it would be just arcsin

Comment: Don't look at things other than the argument!